# Is there any way to import modules outside from app directory using babel?

Tags: node.js, build, babeljs, koa

It might be a stupid question but I think I got stuck in here.

The case is I am using `babel` to compile my `koa` application, the generated build have some issues with dependencies outside from app directory.

The folder structure

```
root/
  node_modules
  auth // auth app
  blog // blog app
  config // common config for both apps
  models // database models common for both apps
  logs // app logs
  builds
    auth // auth build
    blog // blog build
  .env // envrionment settings
  .babelrc // babel config
  package.json
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "auth": "nodemon auth/ --exec babel-node",
  "blog": "nodemon auth/ --exec babel-node",
  "build:auth": "babel auth -d builds/auth --copy-files",
  "build:blog": "babel blog -d builds/blog --copy-files"
},
"devDependencies" {
  "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
  "nodemon": "^1.8.1"
}
```

When I run `npm run build:auth` the build for auth application is generated but only files in the auth directory are transpiled and copied, is there any way I can have files from `config` and `model` directory also copied into the `build/auth` directory.

A help is really appreciated.

Comment: Fix the same using `webpack`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the same using `webpack`, here the solution if you facing the similar issue

Add a `webpack.config.js` in your `root`

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: [path.join(__dirname, 'utility'), path.join(__dirname, 'model'), path.join(__dirname, 'config'), path.join(__dirname, 'middleware')],
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new UglifyJSPlugin({
      exclude: /node_modules/
    })
  ]
}
```

And install some dependencies using `npm`

`npm install --save-dev babel-core babel-loader babel-polyfill uglifyjs-webpack-plugin webpack-node-externals`

Modified the `auth/index.js` and added `import "babel-polyfill";` on the top.

Let me know if you face any issue.